# WCF - Mtom encoding shows binary data for array but also puts out content in text form

Tags: arrays, wcf, encoding, mtom

Trying to understand when using mtom encoding I am getting back binary data for the large array "FileContentArray", but then it also outputs the array in text form. I have pasted the response from Fiddler. The content type is set to Binary but clearly it is in clear text.
Any thoughts?

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header> 
            <e:EncryptedData Id="_6" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference URI="#_3"/>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
                <e:CipherData>
                    <e:CipherValue>
                        <xop:Include href="cid:http%3A%2F%2Ftempuri.org%2F1%2F635934810848921585" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
                    </e:CipherValue>
                </e:CipherData>
            </e:EncryptedData>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <RawLogResponse xmlns="http://merge.com/icc/services/common/logging/datacontract/">
            <Age xmlns="http://merge.com/icc/services/common/logging">30</Age>
            <Author xmlns="http://merge.com/icc/services/common/logging">Nick Khan</Author>
            <CreationDate xmlns="http://merge.com/icc/services/common/logging">3/13/2016</CreationDate>
            <FileContentArray xmlns="http://merge.com/icc/services/common/logging">
                <xop:Include href="cid:http%3A%2F%2Ftempuri.org%2F2%2F635934810848921585" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
            </FileContentArray>
        </RawLogResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

---

--uuid:02d87cf2-1a92-4da9-a26e-348eaa650bee+id=4
Content-ID: http://tempuri.org/1/635934810848921585
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

*+±b°ñ?Ôn>ÅßùŠÿþ6ñ2i—„u.¨÷!¹c.dÓ[.Œµ_¨ÎÊŸ¸'”ú‚tTêH D—A”¡zºW¼|í,cÉ1>;²Dºƒø‰ ü·Ÿç_!h†ýPØ|ÀwªØc¹¼ètÈ:£:ÚálI«jò3¡NÀ›:‰¥-» Œq­©l.T

--uuid:02d87cf2-1a92-4da9-a26e-348eaa650bee+id=4
Content-ID: http://tempuri.org/2/635934810848921585
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

**DevTraceLog Error: 55 : 2015-12-11 02:16:18.068 : 
[Source] TransferJobUtility::ProcessJobs**

Comment: I should mention that the filecontent array is a text file, but with Mtom encoding I was expecting binarydata representation.